# Drupal 7 GMAP module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-gmap

I am using the gmap module for Drupal 7 along with location and node location module enabled.

I have added a simple location field in my article content type. I have enabled the location block to be shown in main content type.

Now during creation of an article when I enter location values as text fields(like countries,cities etc.) without any latitude and longitudes then the map is not displayed on the article node page.

However if i do enter some latitude longitude values(either manually) or using google map's then in the article node page the map is shown.

So anybody has any ideas about this?It should work like even if i enter a country name and state it should show me the map with the marker

Comment: I was having major issue with Drupal 7 and maps as well. I couldn't get gmap or openlayers to work properly. I'm hoping there's a good mapping solution for D7 soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope its not too late for the answer, probably this will be helpful to someone googling for the issue..

I faced similar problems and in the end it turned out that GeoCoding was not enabled in Location module settings for the country which I was adding entries for.

You can enable GeoCoding from Location module settings (admin/config/content/location) 'GeoCoding Options' tab.